# How to update the value of the textview inside the fragment on the click of the button present in the adapter class in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have two buttons: + and -. I want that when I click on the button +, the value of the textview present in the fragment class (outside the listview) is changed. How can I do this ?

This is my Adapter class:

```
public class CartBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<PojoCart> mList;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> mHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    private Integer total;
    private DataBaseHandler dbh;
    private int Id = 1;
    private String value1, value2;
    private int z;
    private FragmentTransactionListener fragmentTransactionListener = (FragmentTransactionListener) new Cart();


    public CartBaseAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<PojoCart> mList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mList = mList;
        dbh = new DataBaseHandler(mContext);


    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.mImgItem = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cart_image);
            viewHolder.mTvItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
            viewHolder.mTvItemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_price);
            viewHolder.mTvNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
            viewHolder.mBtnAdd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
            viewHolder.mBtnMinus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_sub);
            viewHolder.mImgDelete = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_del);


        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        }


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


        final PojoCart pojoCart = (PojoCart) getItem(position);
        viewHolder.mTvItemName.setText(pojoCart.getmItemName());
        viewHolder.mTvItemPrice.setText(pojoCart.getmItemPrice());
        //  viewHolder.mImgDelete.setTag(pojoCart.getmCategoryId());

      /*  try {
            URL url = new URL(pojoCart.getmItemImage());
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            viewHolder.mImgItem.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            //   Log.e("exception", "" + e.getMessage());
        }*/


        viewHolder.mImgItem.setImageBitmap(Utility.StringToBitMap(pojoCart.getmItemImage()));
        viewHolder.mBtnAdd.setTag(pojoCart);
        viewHolder.mBtnMinus.setTag(pojoCart);
        viewHolder.mTvItemPrice.setTag(pojoCart);
        viewHolder.mTvNumber.setTag(pojoCart);
        viewHolder.mImgDelete.setTag(position);

        if (pojoCart.getmQuantity() > 0) {

            viewHolder.mTvNumber.setText("" + pojoCart.getmQuantity());

        } else {

            viewHolder.mTvNumber.setText("" + 0);
        }


        viewHolder.mBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                PojoCart pojoCart = (PojoCart) v.getTag();
                int mValue = pojoCart.getmQuantity();
                mValue++;
                viewHolder.mTvNumber.setText("" + mValue);
                pojoCart.setmQuantity(mValue);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                value1 = viewHolder.mTvNumber.getText().toString();
                value2 = pojoCart.getmItemPrice();
                int x = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(value2);


                //  viewHolder.Dish_rate.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                Log.e("value1", value1);
                Log.e("value2", value2);
                z = x * y;

                pojoCart.setmItemPrice(String.valueOf(z));


                Log.e("z", "" + z);

                if (x > 2) {
                    int n = x - 1;
                    int k = z / n;
                    Log.e("k", "" + k);

                    pojoCart.setmItemPrice(String.valueOf(k));

                } else {

                    pojoCart.setmItemPrice(String.valueOf(z));
                }


                dbh.updateSingleRow(pojoCart.getmCategoryId(), pojoCart.getmItemPrice(), pojoCart.getmQuantity());
                int total = dbh.getTotalOfAmount();
                pojoCart.setmTotalPrice(total);




            }


        });


        viewHolder.mBtnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                                        PojoCart pojoCart = (PojoCart) v.getTag();
                                                        int mValue = pojoCart.getmQuantity();


                                                        if (mValue > 0) {
                                                            mValue--;
                                                            viewHolder.mTvNumber.setText("" + mValue);

                                                            value1 = viewHolder.mTvNumber.getText().toString();
                                                            value2 = pojoCart.getmItemPrice();
                                                            int x = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                                                            int y = Integer.parseInt(value2);

                                                            if (x >= 1) {

                                                                Log.e("value11", value1);
                                                                Log.e("value22", value2);

                                                                int n = x + 1;

                                                                Log.e("n", "" + n);
                                                                int k = y / n;
                                                                Log.e("k", "" + k);

                                                                z = k * x;

                                                                Log.e("z", "" + z);


                                                                pojoCart.setmItemPrice(String.valueOf(z));

                                                            } else {

                                                                pojoCart.setmItemPrice(pojoCart.getmItemPrice());

                                                            }


                                                        }

                                                        pojoCart.setmQuantity(mValue);


                                                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                                                        dbh.updateSingleRow(pojoCart.getmCategoryId(), pojoCart.getmItemPrice(), pojoCart.getmQuantity());


                                                        pojoCart.setmTotalPrice(dbh.getTotalOfAmount());

                                                    }
                                                }

        );

        viewHolder.mImgDelete.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {


                        int categoryId = pojoCart.getmCategoryId();

                        //  int id = (Integer) view.getTag();
                        //   id++;

                        Log.e("removeIdFromTheTable", "" + categoryId);


                        dbh.delete_byID(categoryId);
                        mList.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();


                        pojoCart.setmTotalPrice(dbh.getTotalOfAmount());


                    }
                }

        );


        return convertView;
    }




    private class ViewHolder {

        TextView mTvItemName, mTvItemPrice, mTvNumber;
        ImageView mImgItem, mImgDelete;
        Button mBtnAdd, mBtnMinus;


    }


}
```

This is my Fragment Class:

```
public class Cart extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<PojoCart> mCartList;
    private ListView mListView;
    private CartBaseAdapter mCartBaseAdapter;
    private DataBaseHandler dbh;
    private List<PojoCartDataBase> pojoCartDataBase;
    private TextView mTvProcesscheck, mTvTotalPrice;
    private String ItemName, ItemPrice;
    private String ItemImage;
    private ArrayList<String> mTotalPrice;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private int ItemQuantity;
    int id = 1;
    private String categoryId;
    private int sumOfPrice;
    private PojoCart pojoCart;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);


    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        initialize();
        //  addData();
        displayTotalAmount();


        try {
            getDataFromDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }

    private void initialize() {
        mTotalPrice = new ArrayList<String>();
        mCartList = new ArrayList<PojoCart>();
        mListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview_cart);
        mCartBaseAdapter = new CartBaseAdapter(getContext(), mCartList);
        Parcelable state = mListView.onSaveInstanceState();
        mListView.setAdapter(mCartBaseAdapter);
        mListView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);

        mTvProcesscheck = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_checkout);
        mTvTotalPrice = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_total_price);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        dbh = new DataBaseHandler(getContext());
        mTvProcesscheck.setOnClickListener(this);
        toolbar.setTitle("Cart");


        mCartBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        final RippleView rippleView = (RippleView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ripple_view_cart);


        rippleView.setOnRippleCompleteListener(new RippleView.OnRippleCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(RippleView rippleView) {
                Log.d("Sample", "Ripple completed");

                Fragment fragment = new LogIn();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                toolbar.setTitle("Restaurant List");
            }

        });


    }


   /* private void addData() {


        for (int i = 0; i < mItemName.length; i++) {

            PojoCart pojoCart = new PojoCart();
            pojoCart.setmItemName(mItemName[i]);
            pojoCart.setmItemPrice(mItemPrice[i]);
            pojoCart.setmItemImage(mItemImage[i]);


            mCartList.add(pojoCart);

        }
        //   mCartList.add(pojoCartDataBase);

    }
*/


    private void getDataFromDatabase() throws IOException {

        Cursor c = dbh.getAllRows();


        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {

                //  int id = c.getInt(0);
                int id = c.getInt(1);
                Log.e("id.....", "" + id);
                ItemName = c.getString(2);
                ItemPrice = c.getString(3);
                Log.e("itemname", ItemName);

                Log.e("itemprice", ItemPrice);

                ItemQuantity = c.getInt(4);

                Log.e("itemquantity", "" + ItemQuantity);
                ItemImage = c.getString(5);


                Log.e("itemimage.........", ItemImage);

                pojoCart = new PojoCart();
                pojoCart.setmItemName(ItemName);
                pojoCart.setmItemPrice(ItemPrice);
                pojoCart.setmItemImage(ItemImage);
                pojoCart.setmQuantity(ItemQuantity);

                pojoCart.setmCategoryId(id);


                mCartList.add(pojoCart);
                mCartBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                c.moveToNext();


            }


        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.tv_checkout:
              /*  Fragment fragment = new LogIn();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();*/

                // toolbar.setTitle("Checkout");
        }


    }

    public void displayTotalAmount() {

        int total = dbh.getTotalOfAmount();
        mTvTotalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(total));

    }


}
```

I want to change the value of the `mTvTotalPric` (Textview) on click of the button + and -, which is present at the listview. And the textview which the value I want to change is outside the listview.

Comment: use interface to change the values

Comment: Sir,I don't know how to use interface.can you tell me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Adapter class` create one `interface`

Adapter.class

```
public class CartBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<PojoCart> mList;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> mHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    private Integer total;
    private DataBaseHandler dbh;
    private int Id = 1;
    private String value1, value2;
    private int z;
    private FragmentTransactionListener fragmentTransactionListener = (FragmentTransactionListener) new Cart();
    private SendDataToFragment sendDataToFragment;

    public CartBaseAdapter(FragmentCart fragmentCart, Context mContext, ArrayList<PojoCart> mList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mList = mList;
        dbh = new DataBaseHandler(mContext);
        sendDataToFragment = (SendDataToFragment) fragmentCart;

    }

    //Interface to send data from adapter to fragment
    public interface SendDataToFragment {
        void sendData(String Data);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.mImgItem = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cart_image);
            viewHolder.mTvItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
            viewHolder.mTvItemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_price);
            viewHolder.mTvNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
            viewHolder.mBtnAdd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
            viewHolder.mBtnMinus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_sub);
            viewHolder.mImgDelete = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_del);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


        final PojoCart pojoCart = (PojoCart) getItem(position);
        viewHolder.mTvItemName.setText(pojoCart.getmItemName());
        viewHolder.mTvItemPrice.setText(pojoCart.getmItemPrice());


        viewHolder.mImgItem.setImageBitmap(Utility.StringToBitMap(pojoCart.getmItemImage()));
        viewHolder.mBtnAdd.setTag(pojoCart);
        viewHolder.mBtnMinus.setTag(pojoCart);
        viewHolder.mTvItemPrice.setTag(pojoCart);
        viewHolder.mTvNumber.setTag(pojoCart);
        viewHolder.mImgDelete.setTag(position);

        if (pojoCart.getmQuantity() > 0) {

            viewHolder.mTvNumber.setText("" + pojoCart.getmQuantity());

        } else {

            viewHolder.mTvNumber.setText("" + 0);
        }


        viewHolder.mBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Send data via interface to your fragment
                sendDataToFragment.sendData("Your Data");

                //Your existing code 
            }
        });

        viewHolder.mBtnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Send data via interface to your fragment
                sendDataToFragment.sendData("Your Data");

                //Your existing code 
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }


    private class ViewHolder {

        TextView mTvItemName, mTvItemPrice, mTvNumber;
        ImageView mImgItem, mImgDelete;
        Button mBtnAdd, mBtnMinus;


    }


}
```

Inside your `fragment` implement that `interface` so as soon as your `button` is clicked in your `adapter` you will get the data inside your fragment.

Fragment.class

```
public class FragmentCart extends Fragment implements
        View.OnClickListener, CartBaseAdapter.SendDataToFragment{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        CartBaseAdapter adapter = new CartBaseAdapter(FragmentCart.this, getActivity(), yourList);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendData(String Data) {
        //set this data to your textView
    }
}
```

Comment: Maa'm it gives below error :- java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.aaa.maaqualatnew.activity.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.aaa.maaqualatnew.adapter.CartBaseAdapter$SendDataToFragment   at the constructor CartBaseAdater                                             at the line    sendDataToFragment = (SendDataToFragment) mContext;

Comment: @Ripudaman Can you please implement and check now ?
Note that instead of passing context of MainActivity, I have given FragmentCart as you need to give context of the class which implements the interface.

Comment: Happy Coding :) 
Hope you understood how interface was used to send data !

Comment: yeah :) and thnx for your help !

Answer (score 0):

**Create a interface :**

```
 public interface MyListener {
    // you can define any parameter as per your requirement
    public void callback(View view, int value);
}
```

In your listview adapter use interface like below on click of button + or - like :

```
MyListener ml;
ml = (MyListener) context;
ml.callback(this, "success");
```

In activity implements MyListener than callback method override there and than you get performed action from fragment to activity.

Comment: Dear Sir, My question is I have a  listview. the two button present in the listview + and - . i want to pass value (int total =dbh.getTotalamount) to the textview which is present in the fragment as mTvTotal(outside the listview).please see my code.please

Comment: check edited answer from base adapter of your code button click then value passed through interface to your activity and change textview value at your activity in interface override method.

Comment: Sir,it gives class cast exception at the line ml = (MyListener) context;

Comment: yes. I am using BaseAdapter. and I already use ml = (MyListener) context; in my adapter constructor . but it gives class cast exception.

Comment: ok .. check you gave interface name unique or not, means not match to your other class name. and check import correctly or not in adapter.

Comment: Dear sir, my error is this:-                                                                                             java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.aaa.maaqualatnew.activity.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.aaa.maaqualatnew.adapter.CartBaseAdapter$SendDataToFragment                                                                                                                         can you give me any suggestion to solve this ?

Comment: the exception is you are casting activity context to fragment so try to use base adapter own context . like

public BuyDongleAdapter(Context context) {
 catests = (catest) context;
}

Comment: sir,i am using base adapter own context. please see my code. The exception is occure because in fragment i get  the context as getContext.

Comment: No. i am getting the error at the line ml = (MyListener) mContext;

Comment: Thanx sir ! for your support !