# How to pass value from activity to fragment through view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity which uses view pager to switch between fragments. I have three fragments. While switching between these fragments i have to pass a string value to the fragment class to identify which fragment is selected.Because here I am using same fragment class for all the three fragments. 
Here is my main activity.

```
public class mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public String kind, value;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
public FloatingActionButton upload, send;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
  upload = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.upload_fab);
    send = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.send_message);
    uploadFab.hide();

    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
     kind = mIntent.getStringExtra("KIND");

       viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            Student student =new Student();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:

                    upload.hide();
                    value = "r";

                    break;

                case 1:
                    upload.hide();
                    value = "e";
                    break;

                case 2:
                    upload.show();
                    value = "u";
                    break;

                default:
                    upload.hide();
                    val = "r";
                   break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}
   private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new     ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new RemainderFragment(), "REMAINDER");
    adapter.addFragment(new RemainderFragment(), "EMAIL");
    adapter.addFragment(new RemainderFragment(), "UPLOAD");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
   class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
   }
```

here is my fragment class

```
public class RemainderFragment extends Fragment {
   public RemainderEmailFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.raminder_fragment, container, false);

EditText  subject = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.subject);
EditText des = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.description);
//  String value = mainActivity.value      
       //button to send data

    button = activity.send;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //getting details
            SendData();


         }
    });

    return rootView;
 }


public void SendData() {
    //functon

 }
```

I have tried intents and shared preferences to send data. but nothing worked. I have to get the String value in my fragment class. please help.

Comment: did your try to implement it using interface to pass  your String data ? Something like this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204833/how-to-update-the-value-of-the-textview-inside-the-fragment-on-the-click-of-the/39205174#39205174

Comment: @Bivin you can do this by many ways : one such is using interface , create an interface and implement in your fragment, ask current used fragment from fragment view pager adapter and use that fragment as interface handler by typecasting. Let me know if you require some code also.

Comment: @dex Yes. Can you provide any example code for that? Because I am new to android .

Comment: @ pooja I don't have a separate adapter class. so its bit confusing.

Comment: you can also use broadcastreceiver

Comment: How can I use that ? I never used broadcast receivers before.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code for sample required changes, I have modified your file and added some code to support your requirement.

### Your Activity file

```
    package com.adobe.reader.test;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import com.adobe.reader.R;

    public class mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {

        public String kind, value;
        private TabLayout            tabLayout;
        private ViewPager            viewPager;
        public  FloatingActionButton upload, send;

        // Adding adapter
        private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
            upload = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.upload_fab);
            send = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.send_message);
            uploadFab.hide();

            Intent mIntent = getIntent();
            kind = mIntent.getStringExtra("KIND");

            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            setupViewPager(viewPager);

            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


            // Let's say we need to call some method from fragment in the activity
            Fragment fragment = getCurrentFragment();
            if (Fragment instanceof RemainderFragment)
            {
                RemainderFragment remainderFragment = (RemainderFragment) fragment;
                remainderFragment.setString("Testing string");
            }

            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                   Fragment fragment = getCurrentFragment();
                   if (Fragment instanceof RemainderFragment)
                   {
                        RemainderFragment remainderFragment = (RemainderFragment) fragment;
                   }

                    Student student =new Student();
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:

                            upload.hide();
                            value = "r";
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            upload.hide();
                            value = "e";
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            upload.show();
                            value = "u";
                            break;

                        default:
                            upload.hide();
                            val = "r";
                            break;
                    }
                    remainderFragment.setString(value);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });

        }

        /**
         * This method will give you current fragment used in the viewpager.
         * @return
         */
        public Fragment getCurrentFragment()
        {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if (viewPager != null)
            {
                int currentFragmentIndex = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

                if (adapter != null)
                {
                    fragment = adapter.getItem(currentFragmentIndex);
                }
            }
            return fragment;
        }


        private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new     ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            adapter.addFragment(new RemainderFragment(), "REMAINDER");
            adapter.addFragment(new RemainderFragment(), "EMAIL");
            adapter.addFragment(new RemainderFragment(), "UPLOAD");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
            private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList      = new ArrayList<>();
            private final List<String>   mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

            public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
                super(manager);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return mFragmentList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mFragmentList.size();
            }

            public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
                mFragmentList.add(fragment);
                mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
            }
        }
```

### Your Fragment file

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.adobe.reader.R;

public class RemainderFragment extends Fragment 
{
    public String testingString;

    public RemainderEmailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // Sample method to be called from activity
    public void setString(String testStr)
    {
        testingString = testStr;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.raminder_fragment, container, false);

        EditText subject = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.subject);
        EditText des = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        //  String value = mainActivity.value      
        //button to send data

        button = activity.send;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //getting details
                SendData();


            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }


    public void SendData() {
        //functon

    }
```

Comment: I am still not able to get value. I want to get value inside the string value which i am setting through view pager's onPageScrolled .

Comment: onPageSelected ? just call getCurrentFragment() method there and then set the value "string", you will get in your fragment.

Comment: If you have any issue, I will edit above code to do in similar manner.

Comment: Still no value is setting

Comment: @Bivin please check the edited code, I have update the code according to your requirements.